# Are rankings and player point based levels separate?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

You get player points for doing pretty much anything in the game, but does your ranking (E5-A1) only go up for online matches? Ranked games only?

Also, are the player points you get at the end of a ranked match counted towards your rank, or are those the regular player points you always see and your rank is counted separately from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are considered separate and leveled separately. Playing the more casual modes such as the Global Colosseo online will not count towards your online ranking, only ranked matches do. You can easily test this out yourself by playing a quick ranked match. After the fight is finished, you will gain a certain amount of online rank points based on the results of the match, the difference between both of your current ranks, etc.

As for your other questions - it is likely that the other people who have higher ranks than you but less wins merely played people who were significantly higher ranked than them, and won. For example, fighting someone who is A1 when you're E5 and winning is likely to reward more ranking points than if you were to get a win against someone who is the same rank as you.

For points awarded after a ranked match - unless you see points fill up your ranking meter (which should be done immediately following the conclusion of a fight), it is presumably separate from the points that rank you up.

Comment: Thank you. It's odd, but I've seen people who have less ranked matches than me and less wins, but a higher rank. How is this possible?

Comment: Also, are the player points you get at the end of a ranked match counted towards your rank, or are those the regular player points you always see and your rank is counted separately from that?

Comment: @Maxx I'd recommending adding that to your question, as opposed to asking it here.

Comment: @Maxx I've edited my answer to reflect your new questions.